# Function converting variable Type to Type* creating error C++

Tags: c++, list, class, pointers

I keep getting an error of:

```
In file included from user.h:3:0,
                from sn.cpp:5:
'mylist.h: In member function ‘void MyList<L>::push_back(L) [with L = int]’:
user.h:38:30:   instantiated from here
mylist.h:54:3: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
mylist.h: In member function ‘void MyList<L>::push_back(L) [with L = User*]’:
sn.cpp:61:25:   instantiated from here
mylist.h:54:3: error: cannot convert ‘User*’ to ‘User**’ in assignment
make: *** [sn.o] Error 1
```

I am creating a rudimentary social network where main takes 3 command line arguments - argv[1] is a GML file with nodes containing user information and edges that are user connections.  argv[2] is another file that I have not yet processed. and argv[3] is a GML file that will contain basically a copy of the user information after it has been parsed and put into an ADT list MyList that I wrote, containing instances of User* that hold private data for user id, name, zip code, and age.  For some reason my pushback function to add another item to my list is either making pointers double pointers or nonpointers pointers which creates the error above.  I just cannot figure out where I need to remove a * or what I did wrong. the GML reader function populates two vectors nodes and edges with information such as 
nodes[0] = id 0 name "Mark Redekopp" age 34 zip 90018
nodes[1] = id 1 name "Tommy Trojan" age 124 zip 90007
and 
edges[0] = source 0 target 1
edges[1] = source 1 target 0

The code to write a new GML file is not included yet

sn file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "user.h"
#include "mylist.h"
#include "gmlreader.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  if(argc < 4){
    cerr << "Please provide the input GML file, command file, and output file" << endl;
    return 1;
  }
vector<string>nodes;
vector<string>edges;
GMLReader::read(argv[1], nodes, edges); 
for(unsigned int i =0; i<nodes.size(); i++){
    cout << "node[" << i << "]: " << nodes[i] << endl;
};
for(unsigned int i=0; i<edges.size(); i++){
    cout << "edge[" << i << "]: " << edges[i] << endl;
    cout << "printing an edge!" << endl;
};
cout << "about to create a mylist of users" << endl;
MyList<User*>Users;
cout << "initialized user list" << endl;
for(unsigned int i =0; i<nodes.size(); i++){
    string TextBlob = nodes[i];
stringstream ss(TextBlob);
cout << "started string stream" << endl;
User* newuser = new User; 
    while(newuser->getName()=="" || newuser->getId()==0 || newuser->getZip()==0||        newuser->getAge()==0){  
    if (TextBlob.compare("name")==0){
        string n;
        ss>>n;
        newuser->setName(n);
    }
    else if(TextBlob.compare("age")==0){
        int a;
        ss>>a;
        newuser->setAge(a);
    }
    else if(TextBlob.compare("id")==0){
        int d;
        ss>>d;
        newuser->setId(d);
    }
    else if(TextBlob.compare("zip")==0){
        int z;
        ss>>z;
        newuser->setZip(z);
    }
}
Users.push_back(newuser);
}
return 0;
};
```

mylist.h

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 #include <stdexcept>

 #ifndef MYLIST_H
 #define MYLIST_H

 using namespace std;

 template<typename L>
 class MyList{
private:
    L* data_;
    int len_;
    int MAX_LIST_SIZE;
public:
    MyList();
    ~MyList();
    void push_back(L newVal);
    int size();
    L& at(int loc); 
    bool remove(L val);
    L pop(int loc);
    L& operator[](int loc);
    void changeLen(int new_len){
        len_=new_len;
    }
 };

 int MAX_LIST_SIZE=100;

 template<typename L>
 MyList<L>::MyList(){
        data_ = new L[MAX_LIST_SIZE];
        len_=0;
    };

 template<typename L>
 MyList<L>::~MyList(){
        delete [] data_;
    };

 template<typename L>
 void MyList<L>::push_back(L newVal){
if(len_==MAX_LIST_SIZE-1){
    L* tempList = new L[MAX_LIST_SIZE*2];
    for(int i=0; i<len_; i++){
        tempList[i]=data_[i];
        MAX_LIST_SIZE*=2;
        }
    tempList[len_++]=newVal;
    data_=newVal;
}
data_[len_++]=newVal;
    };

 template<typename L>
 int MyList<L>::size(){
        return len_;
    };

 template<typename L>
 L& MyList<L>::at(int loc){
    if(loc > len_)
        throw invalid_argument("Out of bounds");
return  data_[loc];
};      

 template<typename L>
 bool MyList<L>::remove(L val){
for(int i=0; i<len_; i++){
    if(data_[i]==val){
        for(int j=i; j<len_-1; j++){
            data_[j]=data_[j+1];
        }
        changeLen(len_-1);
        return true;
    };
};
return false;
 };

 template<typename L>
 L MyList<L>::pop(int loc){
if(loc>len_)
    throw invalid_argument("Out of bounds");
L temp;
data_[loc] = temp;
    for(int i=len_; i>=loc; i--){
        data_[i-1]=data_[i];
};
changeLen(len_-1);
return temp;
 };

 template<typename L>
 L& MyList<L>::operator[](int loc){
return  data_[loc];
};

 #endif
```

user.h

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H
#include "mylist.h"

class User{
public: 
    User(){
        name_=""; age_ =0; zip_=0; id_=0;};
    ~User();
    void setName(string name){
        name_=name;
    };
    string getName(){
        return name_;
    };
    void setAge(int age){
        age_=age;
    };
    int getAge(){
        return age_;
    };
    void setId(int id){
        id_=id;
    };
    int getId(){
        return id_;
    };
    void setZip(int zip){
        zip_=zip;
    };
    int getZip(){
        return zip_;
    };
    MyList<int> getFriends(){
        return Friends;
    };
    void addFriend(int friendid){
        Friends.push_back(friendid);
    };
    void printUser(){
        cout<< "User Name: " << name_ << endl;
        cout<< "User Age: " << age_ << endl;
        cout<< "User's Friends: ";
            for(int j=0; j<Friends.size(); j++){
                cout <<Friends.at(j) << " ";
        };
        cout << endl;
    };
private:
    string name_;
    int age_;
    int id_;
    int zip_;
    MyList<int> Friends;
};


#endif
```

Comment: Your question and your code are both illegible.

Comment: That's way too much code, you couldn't narrow it down a bit ?

Comment: Ughh, your code is so tightly packed... How can you read it without your eyes watering!?

Comment: Why not use some of the already-debugged and well-documented container classes that come with the C++ standard library? Or Boost's pointer containers, also debugged and documented. (What's line 54 of `MyList.h`?)

Comment: please: next time you post errors with positions like "mylist.h:54:3" and the whole file, at least provide line numbers. no one likes to count through that. Or make it shorter like suggested.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz we aren't allowed to include those classes - it's for an assignment.  and if I use `L data_;` then the array cannot be dynamically allocated but the `MyList` is supposed to be a list of `User*` so should the newuser be a `User**` ?

Comment: `Users.push_back(newuser);`and  `Friends.push_back(friendid);`  are what generate the errors @scones

Comment: @user2059901: The error is in `mylist.h`, line 54.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `data_=newVal;` but that is in an if statement that should not run unless MAX_LIST_SIZE is exceeded OHH YES THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with what runs or doesn't run. It has to do with what compiles or doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in `push_back`, specifically, this line:

```
data_=newVal;
```

`newVal` is an `L`, but `data_` is an `L*`. I think what you *meant* to say is `data_ = tempList`.

Don't forget to delete the old value for `data_`, though.